# SimpleXml tar.gz

Tags: simplexml, tar

I'm using SimpleXml to parse xmls. Sadly I've approached XML zipped into tar.gz.

When i try to load this XML i get error

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/

Is there any way to work on tared file? If not how can untar this and work on it (it's 12 MB tared file on outside server)?

Kindest regards

Comment: Have you tried [Archive_Tar](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar/)?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Yes the how to untar a file has been asked and answered if not on this Q&A site than on other Q&A site and it's documented with the software you ask about as well. For the last escape, please contact the software vendor for your support options (normally tar comes with man pages). No, we have no clue what you mean about that the file is tared 12 MB on outside server, therefore it is not really clear what you ask about here in specific.